# RKJSONParserKit, storing dictionary leaking? WHat's wrong with this code

Tags: cocoa-touch, restkit

I am using RKJSONParserKit to read json content and store in a NSDictionary

```
parser=[[[RKJSONParserJSONKit alloc] init]autorelease];
NSDictionary *dataDict=[parser objectFromString:response.bodyAsString error:&error];
```

dataDict seems to be leaking, i even tried

```
NSDictionary *dataDict=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[parser objectFromString:response.bodyAsString error:&error]];
```

As far as my understanding, i dont have to release dataDict since am not using alloc/init on it.

The code works as expected, but when tested with "Profiling" - it shows leaks.

ANy advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is not the dictionary "leaking"  but the method objectFromString:error:. Internally I think JSONKit creates some static variables that will appear as "leaks", because they are never released. Unless you have a large memory leak I would say it is normal.

Comment: Thanks Paul, i was just worried before submitting my app. But the app went through to appstore without any hiccups. Probably you are right, it could be jsonkit itself, but am more confident now as my app went through and i know am not doing anything wrong :)